# Program doesn't read csv file

Tags: c, csv, file

Im'new to C and I'm trying to read data from a csv file (which should be an excel file, i think). The program won't read the file and would always print an error message. Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{

    FILE * fpoint = fopen("Cartel1.csv", "r");

    if(fpoint==NULL){
        puts("Error");
    }

    char line[200];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpoint)){
        char *token;

        token=strtok(line, ",");

        while(token!=NULL){
            printf("%-12s", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the only error message printed in this code comes from a failure to open the named file, all fingers (all one of them) point to that as the problem. if you want additional info you can `perror` . I *suspect* the current working directory where you're program is running does not contain the file you think it does (it's in another folder) and thus the `fopen` fails, but that's pure speculation and wild-guessing.

Comment: OP here: But they're all on desktop, that's why i don't understand

Comment: I tried perror and it says "no such file or directory

Comment: unless the actual program is also running with your desktop as the current working directory, that won't work. You can test this by editing your code and providing the *full* path to the file. Don't forget on windows backslashes must be escaped (doubled). If that works, then your program's current working directory, running under whatever IDE you're using and not telling us, is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this program and found the error as "Segmentation fault".

A "segmentation fault" occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system).

For resolving the issue, please try to put both the program file and the .csv file in the same directory(folder) in your desktop.

Comment: The thing is, I'm an absolute idiot. This is my first approach to files and csv and I forgot to convert the excel file in csv. Now it works, only thing is it prints out some junk characters, I don't know why